# PowerPoint.dll (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interop, powerpoint

Descrição do erro:

> Falha na recuperação de fábrica de classes COM do componente com CLSID
>   {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} devido ao seguinte erro:
>   80010001 A chamada foi rejeitada pelo chamado. (Exceção de HRESULT:
>   0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED)).

Já tentei a solução em diversos links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638978/call-was-rejected-by-callee-exception-from-hresult-0x80010001-rpc-e-call-rej

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms228772(v=vs.110).aspx

Basicamente o que faço no código é criar um PowerPoint via MVC e retornar o arquivo para download.

```
        MessageFilter.Register();
        Application powerPointApplication = new Application();
        //powerPointApplication.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;

        var pptPresentation = powerPointApplication.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoFalse);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout =
            pptPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

        //Step5.Insert a slide by calling the Add method on the Presentation.Slides collection, and add some texts to the slide.

        var index = 1;

        var oSlides = pptPresentation.Slides;

        if (model.Configuration.Ratio == "4:3")
        {
            pptPresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = PpSlideSizeType.ppSlideSizeOnScreen;
        }

        foreach (var slide in model.Slides)
        {
            var oSlide = oSlides.AddSlide(index, customLayout);

            oSlide.FollowMasterBackground = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
            //oSlide.Background.Fill.BackColor.RGB = Convert.ToInt32(ExtractHex(model.Configuration.Background), 16);
            oSlide.Background.Fill.BackColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(HexToColor(model.Configuration.Background));

            //content
            var oShape = oSlide.Shapes[2];

            //oShape.LockAspectRatio = MsoTriState.msoTriStateToggle;

            var oTxtFrame = oShape.TextFrame;
            var oTxtRange = oTxtFrame.TextRange;
            oTxtRange.Text = FormatText(slide);
            //oTxtRange.Font.Size = model.Configuration.FontSize;

            oTxtRange.Font.Color.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(HexToColor(model.Configuration.Forecolor));

            oTxtRange.Font.Size = GetFontSize(slide);

            if (model.Configuration.Font != null)
            {
                oTxtRange.Font.Name = model.Configuration.Font;
            }
            //oTxtRange.Font.Bold = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            oShape.TextEffect.Alignment = MsoTextEffectAlignment.msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered;


            oTxtFrame.HorizontalAnchor = MsoHorizontalAnchor.msoAnchorCenter;
            //oTxtFrame.VerticalAnchor = MsoVerticalAnchor.msoAnchorMiddle;

            var format = oTxtRange.Paragraphs().ParagraphFormat;
            format.Bullet.Type = PpBulletType.ppBulletNone;

            //format.Alignment = PpParagraphAlignment.ppAlignCenter;

            index++;
        }

        //Step6.Save the presentation as a pptx file and close it.
        model.Name = "presentation.ppt";
        string fileFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + model.Name;

        pptPresentation.SaveAs(fileFullPath, PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation, MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed);
        pptPresentation.Close();

        powerPointApplication.Quit();

        MessageFilter.Revoke();

        return File(fileFullPath, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", model.Name);
```

Comment: Acredito que você terá que enumerar em sua pergunta os links que já tentou. Assim vai ajudar numa resposta mais direta (sem repetir o que já tentou).

Comment: Adicionando seu código irá ajudar no entendimento da pergunta, o que facilitaria em obter uma resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Já arrumei na pergunta.

Comment: Olá, olhando as páginas relacionadas, não consegui chegar a uma solução, utilizo em meu sistema Delphi o gerado de relatórios, Report Manager, em alguns relatórios mais antigos, onde ao exportar ocorre o mesmo erro, teria alguma solução para este problema?